# Is it OK to ask when to use static or instance methods on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Is it allowed to ask questions (on Stack Overflow) like:

- When should I implement static or instance methods?
- What is the difference between static and instance methods?

Comment: The first of those would be way too broad. The second would suggest a lack of research, as there's a *lot* of information about that difference already.

Comment: Sounds overly broad to me. [programmers.se] could be a better fit, but I suggest you read their help center and look for similar questions there and how they have been written before posting your own.

Comment: See [Java: when to use static methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2671496/1288408)

Comment: Buy CLR Via C#, save the chapters about memory management and how the CLR works for last, and read.  You will not regret it.  (oh, and get @JonSkeet's book C# in Depth, too.)

Answer (score 3):

You could have answered your question if you went through the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help):

- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Your examples are not types of questions that should be asked in Stack Overflow. They can be closed for many [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions): Duplicate, too broad..

Please go through the links I provided above to better understand how Stack Overflow works.